# Bootstrap Button Inside List View Not Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get a button inside a list view in bootstrap to get to two different links and it always follows the list view link, not the button link if I press the button. How do I achieve this?

```
<a href="foo.html" class="list-group-item">
    <p>This links somewhere different than the button</p>
    <button href="bar.html" class="btn btn-success">Example</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be easily accomplished with Bootstrap as-is, but a few tweaks can get us what we want. The main problem is that nested anchors aren't really valid HTML. However, we can achieve the same result by absoultely positioning a link *above* another link.

Have a look at this JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/febivi/2/

In summary:

Add a new class to the list-group that will define our new container:

```
  <ul class="list-group action-list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a class="list-group-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Cras justo odio</a>
      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="http://google.com">Go</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a class="list-group-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Cras justo odio</a>
      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="http://google.com">Go</a>
    </li>  
  </ul>
```

The primary link is ".list-group-link" and the secondary link is the ".btn" action.

Next we add some CSS to style list-group-item's inside action-list-group:

```
.action-list-group {
  position: relative;
}

/* remove the list group padding since our nested anchor tag will now have it */
.action-list-group .list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}

.action-list-group .list-group-item > a.list-group-link {
  display: block;
  /* inherit from .list-group-item */
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #555;
}

/* re-add the link styling */
.action-list-group .list-group-item > a.list-group-link:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.action-list-group .btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Where it says "inherit", if you were using the [Sass version of Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) you could use sass's `@include` or `@extend` to include the same styling as bootstrap's `.list-group-item > a`.

Answer (score 2):

There is javascript solution that you can use as well.  The one benefit being that you can then have your button element in the flow of the list-group.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="foo.html" class="list-group-item">
    <p>This links somewhere different than the button</p>
    <button data-href="bar.html" class="btn btn-success">Example #1</button>
</a>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.list-group-item').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.is('button')) {
        window.location=$target.data('href');
    } else {
        window.location=$target.closest('a').prop('href');
    }
});
```

Basically, the click handler works to prevent the normal behavior of the list-group-item anchor tag using `event.preventDefault()`.  Then using event.target, you can get the element that dispatched the event.  If the target was a button, you retrieve its data property and set the window.location to it.  Otherwise, the jQuery `closest()` method is used to find the nearest anchor tag and use its href value to set the window.location.  In jQuery, the closest method starts with the current element (which could be the anchor itself or any of its ancestors that are not button elements) and travels up the DOM from there.

Also, note that since the button element does not have an href attribute, this example uses a data attribute to store the link reference.